# cant upload image files using laravel

Tags: php, html, laravel

i have problem on my code, i cant pass uploaded file into the request this is my form

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ route('user.update', ['user' => Auth::user()]) }}" autocomplete="off" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            @method('PUT')
            @csrf
<div class="form-group focused">
    <label for="avatar" class="form-control-label">Profile Pic 
<span class="small text-danger">*</span></label>
    <input type="file" class="form-control-file" name="avatar" id="avatar" accept=".jpeg,.jpg,.png">
</div></form>
```

i tried to dump my request variable in my update method in user controller but it return null

```
dd($request->file('avatar'));
```

please help me, ill be very helpful
btw sorry for my bad english

Comment: can you check `dd($request);`

Comment: Add the close tag of your form, </form>

Comment: @EsTeAa i've edited my question sorry

Comment: What is the output of `dd($request->all());`

Answer (score 0):

View File:

```
<form method="post" action="{{ route('user.update', ['user' => Auth::user()]) }}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    @method('PATCH')
    @csrf
    <div class="form-group focused">
        <label for="avatar" class="form-control-label">
            Profile Pic 
            <span class="small text-danger">*</span>
        </label>
        <input type="file" name="avatar" id="avatar">
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: You just change the method, so its do the same

Comment: I think the problem is with your accept that you used in input .